# How to call google map api from dilogflow fulfillment. Please what is wrong with my code?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to be able to implement the code below in a dialogflow webhook...to respond with Distance is : "+ result.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].distance.text); when the intent is matched...

```js
var Request = require("request");
var voso = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ikoyi&destination=egbeda&key****"
Request.get(voso, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Distance is : "+ result.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].distance.text);
    console.log("Duration is : "+ result.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].duration.text);
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Please update your question to indicate where is the `Request` object (with the capital R) is defined.

Comment: You should also update the question with any errors that are being generated or how you know "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Prisoner I forgot to require the request package. I have done that now. The function was hosted on firebase. this is the error i get when i check dignose on dialogflow.Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Please update the question with your current code, then. Also please update the question with the full contents of the error.

Comment: I have updated it...

Comment: @Prisoner please assist....My objective to be able able to respond with traffic time when the intent is matched....

Answer (score 0):

I used axios to make the call. You can put this code in your function. You will need to specify a particular place rather than a generic area and also specify the region which in this context is Nigeria.

```
function Distance(agent) {
let url ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=TBS&destination=zone+park+gbagada&key=AIzaSyD7-V9F5DxU-Mn4WM-CBoI8_Muhtsnu5pM&region=NG';

  return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    var distance = response.data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
    let bot_response = "The distance is " + distance;
    agent.add(bot_response);

  });
}
```